# Problems with Unity shades on android device

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I am trying to build a simple 3d scene which renders fine on my Window's machine but when I build and run it on my Android tablet all shades are gone. 
The scene is pretty simple as it consists of 4 cubes, one ball, 5th cube as the background, a camera and a direction light source. 
Are there any tricks to see the same shades from my PC game window on my android device ?

Comment: Do you mean shadows? Or do you mean material shaders?

Comment: shadows are missing on my android device while i can see them on PC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The computation of shadows depend on the [quality settings](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-QualitySettings.html). (menu: Edit > Project Settings > Quality)

These settings can be different for all the supported platforms. Check that shadows are enabled on android.

Comment: Note that "good shadows" may not be supported at all (so even if you change the quality settings, you still might end up with crappy looking shadows, as mobile devices typically can only support a single pixel light or low-to-medium quality shadowmaps).

Comment: Thank you; it finally worked; my default quality had shadows switched off;